# How to vertically rotate text in table header in ckEditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

How to vertically rotate text in table header in ckEditor? I am using version 4.4.4.

Comment: I want to reproduce like that in my ckEditor table      https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0QGv.png

Comment: do you succeeded in rotating text? I have to rotate an entire table, and I'm looking to  something similar...